# How can I find the longest chain of relations in a database?

Tags: database, algorithm, postgresql, relationship

I have a large postgresql database of artists, songs and cover relations between the songs. I'd like to find the longest chain of cover relations in the database, similar to  http://www.coversproject.com/artist/longest_chain

In the end I want something like this:

- artist A covered song 1 originally by artist B
- artist B covered song 2 originally by artist C
- artist C covered song 3 originally by artist D
- ...

In my use case any artist can only appear once in the list, which makes this even trickier. I also simplified my database structure here to make the question less specific, but this shouldn't be an issue.

It seems to me that there's no magical query that will give me a definitive answer. I think I need some kind of algorithm that queries the database over and over again with a different starting entry, while storing the results of each query run. After a while I'd just pick the longest chain found during that time, which may not be the longest chain existing but good enough for me.

Any pointers to how this could be accomplished? (natively in postgres or writing a script that queries the database)

Comment: Have you looked into postgres' WITH RECURSIVE statement? You might be able to achieve want you want using that.

Comment: How large is large?  It will probably be easiest to read the table out and build linked lists in the obvious manner. Then look for the longest list.  In SQL I'm pretty sure it will take a series of queries.  You should be able to do it in log N queries for a longest chain of length N: Find chains of length 2, 4, 8, etc. until you find a length 2^i with zero elements.  Then binary search to find the actual longest between 2^(i-1) and 2^i - 1.

Comment: This problem is known to be NP-hard by a reduction from the longest path problem for bipartite graphs, meaning that you are unlikely to find a fast algorithm that will be able to solve this problem in a large database.

Comment: @DavidSykes I haven't looked into WITH RECURSIVE, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Gene there are about 200000 relations between the songs, but the actual queries to get to those relations are quite complex, because a song can have multiple originals and can be performed by multiple artists. It will probably take a while until I get an acceptable result using series of queries, but thanks for the hint.

Comment: @templatetypedef I thought so but it was worth a shot, thanks.

Comment: There are quite a few examples for recursive CTE here on SO, Try a [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+with+recursive+cte+path+node&submit=search).

Comment: A recursive CTE is the obvious way. but it will be hard to detect and avoid cycles.

Answer (score 1):

In "The Stanford GraphBase" section FOOTBALL Knuth considers the problem of finding long chains of games between football teams of the form "A beat B by 5, B beat C by 9, C beat D by 43..." to provide an argument that the expected winning margin of A over Z is large. He states that this is an NP-complete problem, and asks for suggestions. What he actually programs up is something he calls stratified greed, which looks a lot like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_search.

A while ago I spent some time playing around with Beam Search for fun, but towards the end started wondering if Limited Discrepancy Search was better - it tends to require that you spend less time saving the state of partial answers, as it is pretty close to backtracking, where you typically make small changes to an answer as you make more assumptions or retract assumptions that don't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I think I've been doing something like this before.  Back then I had a hierarchy, and the problem was "find all children and grandchildren of node X".  This is not very easy to do in a  relational database - so I made a helper table and some script to populate it.  Let's see if I can remember it ... *note: this is freely after my memory and not tested, no warranties whatsoever that I got it right.  My problem was also of a bit different than yours, so I'm not sure if the solution applies.*

```
create table chain_helper (
    head int,
    tail int,
    chain_length int
)
create index chain_helper_by_head(head);
create index chain_helper_by_tail(tail);
```

The idea is for this table to contain all possible links, with head and tail being foreign keys.  My case was a bit easier since I had a strict hierarchy, no loop control needed.  The source table had an id and a parent_id field.  Here is how I populated the table:

Initialize table with the simple links:

```
insert into chain_helper (head, tail, chain_length) 
    select id, parent_id, 1 from source_table;
```

I continued populating the table with all chains of length 2:

```
insert into chain_helper (head, tail, chain_length)
    select parent.head, child.tail, min(parent.chain_length + 1)
    from chain_helper parent 
    join source_table child on source_table.parent_id=parent.id
    where not exists 
       (select * from chain_helper where head=parent.head and tail=child.tail)
    group by parent.head, child.tail;
```

(since I had a strict hierarchy, I didn't need to aggregate - there would be no duplicates in my case).

Repeating will insert all chains of length 3, etc, and the statement can be repeated all until there is nothing more to insert.  Then it's trivial to find the max chain length:

```
select max(chain_length) from chain_helper;
```

This solution doesn't make it easy to display the chain - but that wasn't a requirement in my case.  I mostly used the chain_helper in joins to be able to catch all children and grandchildren of a particular node in the hierarchy - i.e. "total revenue for this subtree":

```
select sum(source_table.revenue) 
from source_table join chain_helper on chain_helper.tail = source_table.id
where chain_helper.head = parent_of_subtree;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I get exactly what you are looking for,a .  However, I would do something like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE chain (artist_id, path) (
    SELECT id, id::text from artist
    UNION
    SELECT a.id, path || ',' || a.id 
      FROM artist a
      JOIN covers co ON (co.covered_by = a.id)
      JOIN chain ch ON (co.originally_by = ch.artist_id)
)
SELECT * 
  FROM artist a
  JOIN chain c ON c.artist_id = a.id
ORDER BY array_upper(string_to_array(c.path, ',')::int[], 1)
LIMIT 1;
```

Note that with lots of artists, performance will not be all that great, but if you can narrow down your search criteria, that can help.